# Make user follow me automatically

Tags: twitter, oauth

I am using Twitter OAuth. When a user clicks on link on my website, twitter asks user to login to allow my application to authorize. After user has authorized my application, I want him to automatically follow me. Is there a way to do that? Or it is not possible and user has to click on "Follow" button to follow me?

Comment: Why would you that in the first place? You should at least ask for the user's consent?

Comment: Because the kind of website I am making will need parents to follow me to get updates on mobile. So basically every parent will follow me but I want to reduce one step from it and see if it can be done automatically because those parents are not very techy. So if any steps reduced to do the job will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find solution to it. I guess it is not possible!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the user  create a friendship with you using this method

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/friendships/create

Comment: But I don't think friendship is the same as following user.

Comment: from the Twitter api docs on friendship.create  "Allows the authenticating users to follow the user specified in the ID parameter"  ie. yes, it is for following